# How to show a dialog with changePage function?

Tags: jquery-mobile, html

I'm trying to create a simple widget using  jQuery mobile. I have a button, and when I click on that button, I want a dialog to appear that will display a date submission form. I defined a div in my html like this:

```
      <div data-role="dialog" id="DatePage" >
        <div data-role="content">
        <form>
                <input type="date" name="date" />
                <input type="submit"/>
        </form> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now, in order to make this dialog appear when I click a button, I've been trying to use the following line of code:

```
$.mobile.changePage("#DatePage");
```

However, when I do this, nothing happens. I've tried adding other arguments and using different variations, but nothing works. From what I've read elsewhere, and from the examples I've seen, this line should show me the dialog, but it simply doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this snippet

```
<button onClick="$.mobile.changePage('#DatePage', {transition: 'pop', role: 'dialog'});">Open Dialog</button>
```

to open your dialog with a button, [see working example](http://jsfiddle.net/RSsRz/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Header</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
      <button onClick="$.mobile.changePage('#DatePage', {transition: 'pop', role: 'dialog'});">Open Dialog</button>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /page -->

  <div data-role="page" id="DatePage">
    <div data-role="content">
      <h1>My Dialog</h1>
      <form>
        <input type="date" name="date" />
        <input type="submit"/>
        <button data-rel="back">Close Dialog</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. I tried with the `onClick` method directly in the html, and I tried putting the code snippet in my .js file, it just won't work. When I put some debug output in the `onClick` method, the output is being shown in the console, but the `changePage` part is still being ignored. Also, the click on the button in your example works only when you click the first time. Is this a normal behavior?

Comment: You might want to prepare a http://jsfiddle.net with your code? You are right, somehow in [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RSsRz/1/) this works only once, this is probably a jsfiddle problem? Because if you copy my code into a html page and use that as example, it works without problems...

Comment: I solved the problem of the dialog not working. Actually, I haven't solved it, I just recreated my html step by step from the beginning an it finally started showing me the dialog. I then compared it with my old html and  haven't noticed any difference.The problem with the dialog being shown only once still remains, but at least it's being shown, which after hours of dealing with the "no dialog" problem makes me really happy. Thank you very much for your help. If I figure out why is the dialog being displayed only once, I'll post the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In my final solution the dialog was triggered by the following code snippet:

> $.mobile.changePage('#DatePage', {transition: 'pop'});

The problem with the dialog being shown only on the first click on the button appeared because the front page was never shown again after the dialog was shown the first time and any of the two button was clicked the dialog disappeared. The page could be seen because it was the dialog's background, but it was actually never there. In order to avoid the problem, I used the following code snippet:

```
<!-- The popup dialog for date selection -->
    <div data-role="page" id="DatePage">

        <div data-role="content">               
            <form id="DateSubmissionForm">
                <input type="date" name="date" />
                <a href="#FrontPage" input-type="submit" data-role="button" class="ui-btn-left">Submit</a>
                <a href="#FrontPage" data-role="button"class="ui-btn-right">Cancel</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The 'submit' and 'cancel' buttons are actually links back to the front page. With this code, the front page is really shown again and the button is again clickable.